# Ajax Iframes -> Check if busy?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, iframe

This is a question regarding Ajax Iframes.

I have a function to open an Iframe, and set its source, however at some points I would need to open multiple Iframes, and set their sources accordingly. The second iframe should only open if the first one has not finished loading.

Psudocode:

// at some point

```
x = iframe;
x.src = 'dothiscode.php'
```

// at some later point

```
if (x.src = not finished loading)
  y = new iframe;
  y.src = 'domorecode.php'
else
  x.src = 'domorecode.php'
```

---

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. Set an onload event to trigger a Boolean 'iframe done' then loop through those booleans and check which iframes are finished, or open.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no other way to do what you have intended except iframes?

Comment: Of course there are plenty of other ways to do what I intend. I would prefer to do it this way however, hence the question.

Comment: I have found a solution for this. It is very well possible to do asynchronous ajax calls on a dynamicly loading stack of iframes